# Get year's Japanese name from Calendar

Tags: swift, calendar

I am working on a custom calendar in my app.
I noticed that in the Japanese Calendar, there are some years that are not numbers **(this is a screenshot from Apple Calendar)**
[image]

Right now I have this code:

```
let year = Calendar(identifier: .japanese).component(.year, from: Date())
print("Current year: \(year)")
```

But the result from that code is `Current year: 2`.
I wanted to know how I can get the year as localized string instead of numbers, so "2 Reiwa" instead of 2.
Thanks

Comment: `component(.year, from: Date())` returns an `Int`, that's normal to get a value like "2". Use  a `DateForamtter` to get `String` from `Date`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [*era name*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_era_name), just like AD/BC in the Gregorian Calendar.

You can use the `G` format specifier to specify it:

```
let f = DateFormatter()
f.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .japanese)
f.dateFormat = "G y"
f.string(from: Date()) // Reiwa 2
```

You can also get it with `component(_:from:)`:

```
Calendar(identifier: .japanese).component(.era, from: Date())
```

But you'd get a rather human-unreadable number `236`, so you should stick with `DateFormatter`.